# How to do Two Pojo List Field Comparison?

Tags: java, for-loop, list-comparison

I want to check each field individually and find the field that has been updated.

```java
public class User{
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private List<Address> resources;
}
```

```java
public class Address{
    private Long id;
    private String street;
    private String position;
}
```

**the method I don't want** 
How do I solve this problem?

```java
List<User> user1 = ...
List<User> user2 = ...
for(int i=0; i<user1.size(); i++){
    if(user1.get(i).getId().equals(user2.get(i).getId()){
       if(!(user1.get(i).getName().equals(user2.get(i).getName())){
         //updated name field
       }
       if(!(user1.get(i).getDescription().equals(user2.get(i).getDescription())){
         //updated description field
       }
       for(int k=0; k<user1.getAddress().size(); k++){

        if(!(user1.get(i).getAddress().get(i).getStreet().equals(user2.get(i).getAddress().get(i).getStreet())){
        //update street field
         }
       }
    }     
 }
```

Thank you for your solution suggestions.

Comment: It's going to be difficult with those fields being private.  You'll have to do it within the POJO unless you use reflection.  What do all of those get() methods in your code example do? Is that reflection?

Comment: Look at a similar question and solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/867442/what-is-the-best-way-to-compare-several-javabean-properties

Comment: I want to compare them from one of my lists comes from the database and one comes from outside as json. As a result, I want to add, delete, update in the database.